# $\overline{X\cap Y} \subseteq \overline{X} \cap \overline{Y}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, proof-verification

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be two arbitrary subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. Show that $\overline{X\cap Y} \subseteq  \overline{X} \cap \overline{Y}$

**Proof**

since 
$X\cap Y \subseteq X$ and $X\cap Y \subseteq Y$

$\implies \overline{X\cap Y} \subseteq \overline{X}$ and $\overline{X\cap Y} \subseteq \overline{Y}$

In other words, $\overline{X\cap Y}$ is present in both $\overline{X}$ and $\overline{Y}$.
$$\implies \overline{X\cap Y} \subseteq  \overline{X} \cap \overline{Y}$$
Is my proof correct?

Comment: It is a quite good proof.

Comment: It seems correct yes

Comment: Am I missing something?  The overline indicates complement set within the given universal set, correct?  So then wouldn't we have $\overline X\subseteq \overline {X\cap Y}$ instead of the other way around?

Comment: Excellent. But I would leave out the "other words". Saying  that $A$ is a subset of $B$ is okay and enough. Saying that $A$ is present in $B$ raises questions like: what is meant by that?

Comment: @abiessu Here overline indicates *closure*.

Comment: @drhab: ah, thank you.  I missed the implication hinted at by the topology tag.

Comment: @MAS The proof is fine; the question title is all math, and should have some non-math words: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9687/guidelines-for-good-use-of-latex-in-question-titles/9730#9730  Also compare this question to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/212149/proof-that-overlinea-cap-b-subseteq-overlinea-cap-overlineb?rq=1

Comment: Also note that it doesn't matter that you are intersecting only two sets.

Comment: It would seem to me that the more demanding proof would be that the closure is unique, which is the assumption you make when you assign such a property as a function, which is the core of your proof, so in my opinion, this proof is correct if you can prove the assumptions that go into it, with uniqueness being the most significant one to me.

Comment: Possible dupe? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/212149/proof-that-overlinea-cap-b-subseteq-overlinea-cap-overlineb?rq=1

Comment: If this is for a basic course, you might want to justify the first implication by appealing to the definition of closure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

There's really not much more to say about it. The steps are trivial and clear. One might even regard the whole statement as obvious.