# $\overline{X\cap Y}\subset \overline{X}\cap\overline{Y}$ for real numbers, case when $\overline{X\cap Y}\neq \overline{X}\cap\overline{Y}$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

My proof for this is similar to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1086610/overlinex-cap-y-subseteq-overlinex-cap-overliney), but I can't find an example such that $\overline{X\cap Y}\neq \overline{X}\cap\overline{Y}$ for the **real numbers**.

Comment: Is there in any way implied that $X \neq Y$? Otherwise I don't see how you could prove it or if it is even true. It could be that I have the wrong definition of closure though (if it is closure you are implying in the question, the bar could also mean complement)

Comment: Nvm, I found a good example here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77373/give-an-example-that-overlinea-cap-b-neq-overlinea-cap-overlineb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy example: $X = (0,1), Y = (1,2)$.  Their intersection is empty, but the intersection of their closures is not.

Answer (score 5):

The rationals and the irrationals will do.